# Can the probability of human extinction be computed from some model?

Tags: risk-management, futurism

In a recent survey (https://www.newscientist.com/article/2410839-theres-a-5-chance-of-ai-causing-humans-to-go-extinct-say-scientists/) a majority of AI researchers considers a non negligible risk of human extinction due to the development of superhuman AI.

Can this probability be computed from some model, even if crude?

Risk models are used elsewhere, from the return of a long-term investment portfolio given the distribution of yearly return and some independence assumption, to the study of extinction of species in natural environments.

Comment: By development of "AI", you mean "AGI" or "superintelligence", right? It might be a good idea to clarify this, as this always poses questions and leads to ambiguity. Some may consider that we already have "AI"and the development of "AI" has clearly not led us to extinction, at least for now.

Comment: The chance of human extinction is 1 in any case. It's just a question of *when*. I always cringe when I see "risk of death". It is certain, no risk at all.

Comment: The question is what model (formula) yields your 1.